# image file path in DCIM is returned as false

Tags: android, filepath, android-4.4-kitkat

I see the image file in DDMS file explorer as /mnt/shell/emulated/0/DCIM/myPicsFolder/, if I write

```
final String uploadFilePath = "/mnt/shell/emulated/0/DCIM/myPicsFolder/";
final String uploadFileName = "mypic.jpg";
String sourceFileUri = uploadFilePath + uploadFileName;
File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
if (sourceFile.isFile()) {/*Upload Image*/}
```

but the if statemente returns false :-/ , what's wrong? I'm testing code in Samsung Core 2 with Android 4.4. I've checked and rechecked if the path is correctly written and it's ok.

Comment: `What's wrong?` You're using the emulator path on the phisical device: /mnt/shell/ **emulated** /0/DCIM/myPicsFolder

Answer (score 2):

> what's wrong?

Root paths in **`adb shell`** are not the same as root paths for your app. **Never hardcode root paths in your app**. Always use methods on `Environment` or `Context` to get at root paths.

In this case, `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM)` will give you a `File` pointing to the `DCIM` directory that you are trying to work with. So, use something like:

```
File dcim=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
File sourceFile=new File(new File(dcim, "myPicsFolder"), "mypic.jpg");
```

Comment: dcim now has a value */storage/emulated/0/DCIM* and sourceFile is */storage/emulated/0/DCIM/myPicsFolder/mypic.jpg* and again the if statement is false :-/, then this means myPicsFolder is not there.

Comment: @JoeCoolman: Have you ever created that directory and this file? "then this means myPicsFolder is not there" -- or it means that `mypic.jpg` is not there, or that `mypic.jpg` is not a file (e.g., it is a directory).

Comment: dcim.isDirectory() returns true ! but `File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
             Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "myPicsFolder");file.isDirectory()` returns false. My device is connected via MTP and if I navigate in folders I see this: [DCIM](http://juydroid.freevar.com/dcim.png) and [inside DCIM](http://juydroid.freevar.com/dcim_vacio.png) and similarly in the other folders like Metal or Music where I do know they aren't empty. I can't see the files or folders inside the folders.

Comment: I didn't take into account to add in manifest *<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>* I waste my afternoon in this issue >:( thanks anyway. My original code now works along with the corrections of @CommonsWare